# How to plot the trajectory that fminsearch follows?

Tags: matlab, fminsearch

I am trying to optimize rosenbrock's function with `fminsearch` and also drawing the point that gives the minimum value with point size being proportional to the iteration number at each iteration on the 2-D contour plot of rosenbrock's function, however that's not a good idea. As  the point size gets bigger it's difficult to see other points. Instead I would like to plot the trajectory `fminsearch` follows so that I can see the path clearly. How would one do that?

I couldn't find a way to do it as you only get a single point passed to the `outputFcn`.

Here is my plot:
[image: Rosenbrock]

Here is an example of how I would like it to look like (just to clarify what I want):
[image]

```matlab
options = optimset('outputFcn', @out, 'Display', 'iter');
x = [3.5    2.5     0.5     0.5];
y = [0      -2      -2      0];
[x,fval,eflag,output] = fminsearch(@rosenbrock_wrapper, [x(4), y(4)], options)
title 'Rosenbrock solution via fminsearch'

%Rosenbrock Function
function val = rosenbrock(x, y)
% a = 1.5, b = -1
val = (1 - x + 1.5) .^ 2 + 100 * (y + 1 - (x - 1.5) .^ 2) .^ 2;
end

%Rosenbrock Wrapper
function val = rosenbrock_wrapper(X)
val = rosenbrock(X(:, 1), X(:, 2));
end

%Output Function
function stop = out(x, optimValue, state)
stop = false;
switch state
    case 'init'
        fcontour(@rosenbrock, [0 3 -3 3], 'MeshDensity',50, 'LineWidth', 2, 'LevelList', 1:5:300);
        hold on;
    case 'iter'
        plot(x(1), x(2), '.', 'MarkerSize', optimValue.iteration + 1);
end
end
```

Comment: It's easiest with the entire time-vector of all states. You could create a global variable, to which you add the current state at every iteration in the `'OutputFnc'`. After `fminsearch` converged, you call the global variable in the base workspace and plot it as a simple line plot

Comment: Yes, I just didn't want to use a global variable and wanted to see whether anyone could come up with a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to plot the progress of the optimization problem real time, you can use the `PlotFcn` option of `fminsearch` (see [docs](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/plot-functions.html) for more info).

```
options = optimset('PlotFcn', @myplotfnc, 'Display', 'iter');

x = [3.5    2.5     0.5     0.5];
y = [0      -2      -2      0];
[x,fval,eflag,output] = fminsearch(@rosenbrock_wrapper, [x(4), y(4)], options)


%Rosenbrock Function
function val = rosenbrock(x, y)
% a = 1.5, b = -1
val = (1 - x + 1.5) .^ 2 + 100 * (y + 1 - (x - 1.5) .^ 2) .^ 2;
end

%Rosenbrock Wrapper
function val = rosenbrock_wrapper(X)
val = rosenbrock(X(:, 1), X(:, 2));
end

% plot function
function stop = myplotfnc(x,optimValues,state)
    persistent pline; % make handle to line peristent between function calls to add new data points
    stop = false;
    switch state
        case 'init'
            fcontour(@rosenbrock, [0 3 -3 3], 'MeshDensity',50, 'LineWidth', 2, 'LevelList', 1:5:300);
            hold on;
            pline = plot(x(1), x(2), '.-', 'linewidth', 2);
            text(x(1), x(2), num2str(optimValues.iteration));
        
        case 'iter'
            % append data to line object
            pline.XData(end+1) = x(1);
            pline.YData(end+1) = x(2);
            text(x(1), x(2), num2str(optimValues.iteration));
    end
end
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can let the output function assign the x,y data to the base workspace after all iterations. Then you can just plot them like you are used to.

```
%Output Function
function stop = out(x, optimValue, state)
persistent xy_data
stop = false;
switch state
    case 'init'
        xy_data(1,:) = [x(1), x(2)];
    case 'iter'
        xy_data(end+1,:) = [x(1), x(2)];
    case 'done'
        stop = xy_data; % get output when calling after simulation
end
end
```

And to get the data after the optimization, you just have to do:

```
xy_data = out([],[],'done');
figure(); 
plot(xy_data(:,1), xy_data(:,2));
```

Comment: That is awesome! I didn't know you could append like that. Though someone had answered a different solution on MathWorks -which I've posted here as well, I like your approach more. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent answer. But instead if `assignin`, I would do `stop = xy_data`. This way, you can get your results by `data = out([],[],'done')`. Now you can control the variable name that data is stored in in the base workspace, or you can get the data from a calling function, without polluting the base workspace.

Comment: @CrisLuengo ah yeah that's better, thx for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Besides @rinkert's brilliant answer I would like to post another way of doing this which was posted as an answer to my question on [MathWorks](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/658023-how-to-plot-the-trajectory-that-fminsearch-follows?s_tid=srchtitle) by **Matt J**.

```matlab
trajectory=doIt();
fcontour(@rosenbrock, [0 3 -3 3],'LineColor',   '#00FFFF', 'MeshDensity',50,...
                                 'LineWidth', 2, 'LevelList', 1:25:300);
hold on
plot(trajectory(1,:),trajectory(2,:),'ks-','MarkerFaceColor','k')
plot(trajectory(1,end),trajectory(2,end),'ro','MarkerSize',20)
hold off
title 'Rosenbrock solution via fminsearch'
```

[image: Rosenbrock's function]

```matlab
function history=doIt
options = optimset('outputFcn', @out, 'Display', 'none');
x = [3.5    2.5     0.5     0.5];
y = [0      -2      -2      0];
history=[];
[x,fval,eflag,output] = fminsearch(@rosenbrock_wrapper, [x(4), y(4)], options);
 
    %Output Function
    function stop = out(x, optimValue, state)
        stop = false;
        switch state
            case 'iter'
                history=[history,x(:)];
        
        end
    end
end
%Rosenbrock Function
function val = rosenbrock(x, y)
% a = 1.5, b = -1
val = (1 - x + 1.5) .^ 2 + 100 * (y + 1 - (x - 1.5) .^ 2) .^ 2;
end
%Rosenbrock Wrapper
function val = rosenbrock_wrapper(X)
val = rosenbrock(X(:, 1), X(:, 2));
end
```